# Dropdown is not showing options on first click in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, html-select

I have a dropdown which is using knockout JS

```
<select data-bind="options: OptionsCollection,  optionsCaption: '--Select One--', optionsValue: 'ValueForOptions', optionsText: 'TextForOptions', value: selectedValue, event:{change: changedFunction}"></select>
```

It is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla firefox but in IE when I first click on the dropdown it doesn't show the options, upon clicking next time it loads all the options and shows the list.

This is working fine if I am OptionsCollection is hardcoded. But when I am binding it with server side data its behaving like mentioned above.

```
 this.OptionsCollection(getCollectionData);

 getCollectionData(Id: number) {
 return Rest.GET("_api/Controller/Method", { "id": claimId })
}
```

Server side data as in the data is being fetched from server by calling getCollectionData, and this call goes to webApi controller and some method which returns array of options keyvalue pairs
On first click it shows like:

[image]

On second click it shows: //and also I can see all the options in the DOM even on first click

[image]

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/7tgx3gx5/) works just fine for me in IE11. Please make sure your question contains a minimal repro of your problem. You can edit to add the needed details.

Comment: You are right it's working fine if I bind it with hardcoded data, but if the data is coming from server its behaving as I reported. Weird thing is that it's working fine in chrome and firefox.

Comment: @user1456593 Please explain what you mean by "if the data is coming from the server." Share code, if possible.

Comment: I have no doubt that you are actually experiencing the problem in the real scenario's, but we need a repro to be able to help you. See "[mcve]" for guidance.

Comment: I've put some api call so that you understand what I mean by server side data.

Comment: I can also share screen shots I think that might help

Comment: Don't know if you solved the problem but still... If you are getting the contents of the options list from a remote server, you are actually creating a **competition** in which the response from the server might arrive too late, and hence upon first click there is still no data but there is upon the second click. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was missing reference to bluebird.js. Somehow chrome and mozilla kept that in cache or something. IE wouldn't let my promise work hence causing this issue.